# unzip the files in Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud, unzip

I am using CloudBerry Explorer. And there are some files that I want to unzip them. First, I can find these files' addresses. For expamle; user/abc. And in this abc, there are 5 zip files. How can I unzip them, and merge them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **java.util.zip** package. I suggest you read through the explanation: [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)